# Unable to update tm and NLP packages

Tags: r, nlp, updates, tm

I'm using macOS Sierra Version 10.12.6

I haven't used R-Studio for a long time, so I was prepared to run updates on both R Studio and the packages. My RStudio is Version 1.0.153, but it seems like there is no tm-package or NLP-package that is compatible? I get the following message:

`Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) : 
  namespace ‘slam’ 0.1-32 is being loaded, but >= 0.1.37 is required
In addition: Warning message:
package ‘tm’ was built under R version 3.2.5 
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tm’`

and for NLP:

```
Warning message:
package ‘NLP’ was built under R version 3.2.5
```

At the risk of sounding obtuse, I wonder if I need to install new text mining packages. When I click Update inside RStudio, it tells me all packages are updated, so it seems as if these packages don't have a version beyond 3.2.5.

Comment: You need to update your version of R. The current version is 3.4.1. R and Rstudio are independent pieces of software.

Comment: Thank you! Updating R certainly helped. At least my problem has evolved. i am now being told: ‘ROAuth’ is not available and has been replaced
by .GlobalEnv However, when I try to install the 'GlobalEnv' in RStudio I get the message that is not available (for R version 3.4.1) I wonder what I now need to use to get API authentication..

Comment: Maybe you need to update/reinstall all of your packages.

Comment: I uninstalled and reinstalled the packages that I use. It seems to work, although I'm not sure because I get "Error: object 'OAuthFactory' not found"